# Connecting points with a line in scatterplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatterplot that breaks the points out into different colors by the category. I want one of these categories to have a line connecting the dots to highlight this category's data. I'm having trouble figuring this out...

```
Round <- read.csv("http://goo.gl/3c3vBU") # Data

qplot(factor(Round), Opp.Landed, data=floyd, color=Opponent, size=Opp.Percent.Landed, alpha = I(0.7)) + 
  labs(x="Round", y="Punches Landed", title="Opponent Punches Landed / Percentage", colour="Boxer", size="Connect Percentage") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=1:2, labels=c("Boxer", "Connect Percentage")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))
```

The `ftheme` code is just colors and formatting. Any ideas? I've tried adding `geom_line(aes(linetype=floyd[Opponent="Manny Pacquiao"]), size=1)` but it errors out with

```
Error in [.data.frame`(floyd, Opponent = "Manny Pacquiao") :    unused argument (Opponent = "Manny Pacquiao")
```

EDIT: I've updated the code above to exclude ftheme so it's reproducable. Please see the sample dataset from with three categories. I just want any one of these to have connected points: http://goo.gl/3c3vBU

Comment: Minimum working examples are really helpful for these types of questions. If you don't get the answer you're looking for, you could consider adding a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
 geom_line(data=subset(floyd,Opponent=="Manny Pacquiao"), aes(factor(Round), Opp.Landed, group=Opponent), size = 2)
```

[image]

Very easy piece of code which makes a subset of your data of which gives a nice line of size 2 through your data points.

(for the image I used the opponent Miguel Cotto since you did not provide Manny Pacquiao in the data set)

Answer (score 4):

I can't give a tailored answer without being able to run your code on a sample of your data, but you can use `scale_color_manual` to set the colour of the category you want to highlight to, say, "red" and set all the others to `NA`. For example, if the category you want to highlight is the second category and you have a total of five categories, then add this to your plot code:

```
scale_colour_manual(values=c(NA, "red", rep(NA,3)))
```

If you have points that are tied to the color aesthetic as well, then you'll need to change the points to a fill aesthetic (e.g., `fill=Opponent`) and use a filled point marker that you can set manually using `shape` or `pch`. Otherwise, your point markers will disappear along with the lines. Marker numbers 21 through 25 are filled (see `?pch` for more on point markers).

**UPDATE:** Here's my attempt using the data you provided. I'm not exactly sure how you want the legends and other details to look, so let me know if this works. I've switched to `ggplot`, as I don't know the ins and outs of `qplot`.

```
ggplot(floyd, aes(factor(Round), Opp.Landed, color=Opponent, 
                  fill=Opponent, group=Opponent, size=Opp.Percent.Landed), 
       alpha = 0.7, pch=21) +
  geom_point(pch=21, colour=NA) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Round", y="Punches Landed", title="Opponent Punches Landed / Percentage", 
       colour="Boxer", size="Connect Percentage") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=1:2, labels=c("Boxer", "Connect Percentage")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(hcl(15,100,65), NA, NA), guide="none") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))
```

[image]